Counting "perfect a:b" sequences
I was given this question :
a sequence of black and white balls is "$a:b$ perfect" if it starts and ends with a white ball, and in between every $2$ consecutive white balls there are at least $a$ black balls but at most $b$ black balls ($a$ and $b$ are given parameters). how many $a:b$ perfect sequences of lenght $n$ are there? it is also given that $2a \ge b$.
The answer should be given in recursive form.
Heres my attempt :
sum the number of possibilites for each possible ending sequence, that is $f(n-a-1)+f(n-a-2)+ \ldots +f(n-b-1)$ (each time im subtracting the last sequence of black balls + the last white ball).
does anyone see a more elegant way to get the soultion? with no summations?
any help would be much appricated !

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

You don't say what the question is.  It seems like it is how many a:b perfect sequences of length $n$ are there?  Is that what $f(n)$ is supposed to be?  Please define those.  You can certainly incorporate a $\sum$ to make less writing.

Do you mean every two consecutive white balls?  Or really, any two white balls?  The latter condition would put a hard bound on the length of such a sequence.

I edited the question - yes what i meant is every 2 consecutive white balls
